# Scala: lightweight way to put Arrays in a Set or Map

Tags: arrays, scala, set, equals, hashcode

Since `==` does not work with Arrays, I cannot effectively create a Set of Arrays (or Map with Array keys).  I would rather not take the performance hit of converting my Arrays to a Vector or List or something.  Is there a lightweight way to define natural comparison and hashcode on Arrays so I can stick them in a Set?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use [`WrappedArray`](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.collection.mutable.WrappedArray) from `collection.mutable`. It provides proper equality for arrays with a minimal overhead. `apply`, `update` etc calls are delegated to underlying array. Also there are special classes for primitive types (e.g. `WrappedArray.ofInt`) to avoid boxing and unboxing.

```
scala> new WrappedArray.ofInt(Array(2, 3, 4))
res35: scala.collection.mutable.WrappedArray.ofInt = WrappedArray(2, 3, 4)

scala> new WrappedArray.ofInt(Array(2, 3, 4))
res36: scala.collection.mutable.WrappedArray.ofInt = WrappedArray(2, 3, 4)

scala> res35 == res36
res37: Boolean = true
```

Comment: Or just `genericWrapArray(Array(2,3,4))`, which is in `Predef` so you don't need an import

Comment: There are also some primitive-specific array-wrapping methods: `wrapIntArray`, `wrapFloatArray` etc, which might avoid autoboxing for primitive arrays

Comment: It's worth noting that `WrappedArray` is not a subclass of `Array` (`Array` is `final`), so you'll have to declare your `Set` to contain `WrappedArray` or `IndexedSeq` or something.