# Set of WrappedArray: Type arguments [Int] do not conform to method empty's type parameter bounds [T <: AnyRef]

Tags: scala

I'm trying to make a function that calculates how many combinations of elements with repetition there are given an array of values and a exact sum value.

But I'm getting an error:

```
Error:(23, 38) type arguments [Int] do not conform to method empty's type parameter bounds [T <: AnyRef]
r(maxValue,WrappedArray.empty[Int],Set[WrappedArray[Int]]()).size
```

It seems there is a type problem in the empty set I'm trying to pass to the function.

I choosed WrappedArrays following this [question]: [Scala: lightweight way to put Arrays in a Set or Map](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8219541/scala-lightweight-way-to-put-arrays-in-a-set-or-map) in order to be able to have a set of arrays without duplicates.

```
import scala.collection.mutable.WrappedArray

def Combinations(maxValue: Int): Int = {
    val values= Array(1,2,5,10)
    def r (a:Int,can:WrappedArray[Int],sol:Set[WrappedArray[Int]]): Set[WrappedArray[Int]] ={
        values.map(x=> if (a-x > 0) r(a-x,can:+x,sol) else if (a-x == 0) sol + (can:+x).sorted else sol).reduce((x, y)=>x union y)
    }
    r(maxValue,WrappedArray.empty[Int],Set[WrappedArray[Int]]()).size
}

Combinations(4)
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`WrappedArray.empy` is bounded by `AnyRef`, as `Int` inherits from `AnyVal` you cannot declare your wrappedArray this way.

However you can declare your empty array this way `new WrappedArray.ofInt(Array())`

Here is a little fiddle for you

https://scalafiddle.io/sf/PioRREd/0

Answer (score 2):

I've never seen anyone ever importing `WrappedArray` for anything. It's a rather obscure implementation detail for providing collection methods on ordinary arrays, it has no place in the solution of combinatoric problems. Another general remark: `methodNames` are written in camel-case, starting with a lowercase letter.

Here is a more idiomatic (and also much simpler) solution:

```
def numCombinations(
  sum: Int,
  coins: List[Int] = List(1, 2, 5, 10)
): Long = {
  coins match {
    case Nil => if (sum == 0) 1L else 0L
    case h :: t => {
      (0 to sum / h)
      .map { i => numCombinations(sum - i * h, t) }
      .sum
    }
  }
}

println(numCombinations(4))
```

Example: for `n = 4`, it will find the combinations

```
1 + 1 + 1 + 1
1 + 1 + 2
2 + 2
```

and output `3`.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer, my point in using WrappedArrays was having a way to put them in a Set to avoid duplicates while getting possible solutions. Anyway, I'm not looking for all the combinations that not exceed a maximum but the ones that sum that maximum.

Comment: @Siodh If it's not an upper bound on anything, then why are you calling it "maximum" in the first place? Regardless of whether it maximum sum or just sum, you still don't need any `Set`s for this problem, and you definitely don't need any `WrappedArray`s, simply because no one needs them ever. Updated the question to compute the number of combinations for the exact sum.